# Kendo UI TreeView drag & drop auto scroll

Tags: kendo-ui, scroll, treeview, draggable

I have this code from the kendo examples:
http://dojo.telerik.com/OBEtu

How can I make the treeview to scroll up/down when dragging an element up/down?

Comment: While dragging the element move the wheel of your mouse or scroll using the touchpad. It works for me. Which environment are you using (Device/OS/Browser)?

Comment: I don't want to use the wheel of my mouse, because not all mice have the wheel. Isn't there a way to do this automatically??
I am using Windows 7, Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m.

Comment: Interestingly, the desired behavior does work in Chrome. As you drag the item towards the boundary of the container it auto-scrolls. What's your target browser?

Comment: This is really strange. What version of Chrome are you using? My target browser is Chrome.